# Show time from database in datetime picker

Tags: laravel, datetimepicker

I am developing an application in laravel and use datetimepicker to set time of event at time of add new event. Now I want to update that event detail and I want to show time which I have set at time of add event in respective field.

How can I achieve this using date time picker? My code is as below:

```html
<div class="input-group date start_time col-md-5" data-date="" data-date-format="hh:ii" data-link-field="starttime" data-link-format="hh:ii">
   <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="{{$event_detail['start_time']}}" readonly>
   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="starttime" value="{{$event_detail['start_time']}}" name="starttime"/><br/>
```

```js
$('.start_time').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 1,
    minView: 0,
    maxView: 1,
    forceParse: 0
});
```

When I have try above code it will give me error in console like:

> "TypeError: d is undefined".

But if I blank value attribute if textbox then it work fine. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace value like this, if you are sure the time field will not contain null value, you can skip the empty check but not important though.

```
<input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="{{ $event_detail['start_time'] ? date('H:i',strtotime($event_detail['start_time'])) : '' }}" readonly>
```

Comment: did u refer to the vendor documentation for the library you are using, there are so many date-time pickers, `<div class="input-group date start_time col-md-5" data-date=""`, may be you have to load the value in this part `data-date` instead in the value, but i cannot guarantee without knowing which particular library you are using

Comment: I am using "bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" for date time picker

Comment: are you loading  `moment.js` libs? , and are you using modal window for editing or normal?

Comment: Yes i am loading moment.js libs. and I am using normal editing